# ElasticSearch (Nest) - Ignoring Apostrophes

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am quite new to Elasticsearch. I've been trying to implement a fairly basic search functionality that would ignore apostrophes. I found this bit of  [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer). For the implementation I used Nest library:

```
[ElasticsearchType]
public class MappingTest
{
  [Text(Analyzer = "english")]
  public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Indexing/Search:

```
var indexName = "testindex";
var connectionSettings =
    new ConnectionSettings(
        new Uri("https://url.com"))
        .DefaultIndex(indexName).EnableDebugMode();var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

if (client.IndexExists(Indices.All, descriptor => descriptor.Index(indexName)).Exists)
    client.DeleteIndex(indexName);

var response = client.CreateIndex(indexName, i => new CreateIndexDescriptor(indexName)
    .Mappings(ms => ms
        .Map<MappingTest>(m => m.AutoMap())
    ).Settings(s => s
        .Analysis(a => a
            .Analyzers(aa => aa
                .Custom("english", ca => ca
                    .Tokenizer("standard")
                    .Filters("english_possessive_stemmer", "lowercase")
                )
            )
            .TokenFilters(
                t => t.Stemmer("english_possessive_stemmer", d => d.Language("possessive_english")))
            .TokenFilters(
                t => t.Stemmer("english_stemmer", d => d.Language("english")))
            .TokenFilters(
                t => t.Stop("english_stop", d => d.StopWords("_english_")))
        )
    ));


var obj = new MappingTest() { Title = "Example's" };


var indexResponse = client.Index(obj);

var term = "example";

QueryContainer commonQuery =
    Query<MappingTest>.QueryString(qs => qs.Query(term).DefaultField(f => f.Title));

var searchResponse = client.Search<MappingTest>(s => s.Query(x => commonQuery));
var debug = searchResponse.DebugInformation;
```

I tried a few approaches, but every single time I don't get any results. I would appricate some help.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. You don't need to specify your own custom `"english"` analyzer as it's built into Elasticsearch. If you wanted to **[implement your own analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-analyzers.html)** based on it, then you would need to specify it as you are. In your case here, I don't think you want to specify your own since your custom analyzer only uses `english_possessive_stemmer` and `lowercase` token filters.
2. Multiple calls to `.TokenFilters()` will mean that only the last call wins; calls perform assignment generally in NEST so you would want

   ```
   .TokenFilters(t => t
       .Stemmer("english_possessive_stemmer", d => d.Language("possessive_english"))
       .Stemmer("english_stemmer", d => d.Language("english"))
       .Stop("english_stop", d => d.StopWords("_english_")))
   ```
3. The `Text` attribute on the POCO property `Title` determines the analyzer used for the field
4. An indexed document does not become available for search until after the refresh interval has elapsed (default is 1 second) and the newly indexed document is written to a new segment. In your example, I suspect your search is running before the document is available for index

I'd recommend using the **[Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html)** to play with analyzers. You can create the index and the mapping for your type, then analyze a piece of text using the mapping for a particular field

```
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var defaultIndex = "default-index";
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
        .PrettyJson()
        .EnableDebugMode(response =>
            {
                if (response.RequestBodyInBytes != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        $"{response.HttpMethod} {response.Uri} \n" +
                        $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.RequestBodyInBytes)}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{response.HttpMethod} {response.Uri}");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();

                if (response.ResponseBodyInBytes != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Status: {response.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                             $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.ResponseBodyInBytes)}\n" +
                             $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Status: {response.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                             $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
                }
            });

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

    client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, i => i
        .Mappings(ms => ms
            .Map<MappingTest>(m => m
                .AutoMap()
            )
        )
    );

    client.Analyze(a => a
        .Index(defaultIndex)
        .Field<MappingTest>(f => f.Title)
        .Text("Example's")
    );
}

[ElasticsearchType]
public class MappingTest
{
    [Text(Analyzer = "english")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

You can see that the analyzer returns the following token for `Example's`

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "exampl",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How to implement this in [URI Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html#search-uri-request)?